# Primefaces Sheet ajax event="change" for multiple rows after dragged

Tags: ajax, primefaces, primefaces-extensions

I want to update multiple some rows which dragged for certain column. But ajax update only works for first row. Ajax event change Not works for other rows.

Image Example Of İssue

[image: 1]

As you can see in image i dragged required column and they set to same value. I want to update BigDecimal column according to these cells. But ajax update works 1 time for first row.
In my sheet i am using like below:

`<p:ajax event="change" update="something" listener="#{someBean.editActionListener}"/>`
and catch in backing bean with `public void editActionListener(final SheetEvent event)` method.

My JSF VERSION : 2.2.1
PRİMEFACES AND PRIMEFACES EXTENSION VERSION : 6.2

Comment: I feel like this was fixed in later sheet versions.  PF 6.2 is outdated if you can reproduce on PFE 12.0.3 which is the latest then I would report a bug here: https://github.com/primefaces-extensions/primefaces-extensions/issues

Comment: Also the SheetEvent should contain all the cells that were modified inside of it.